# When a space is NOT locally compact, does it have dense remainder in its compactification?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, lp-spaces, compactification

Any space has to be dense in any of its compactifications (that is part of the definition).

**Question 1)** When the space is NOT locally compact, does that mean that also its remainder in any of its compactifications is **always** dense?

As an example, $l^2$ is dense in its Stone-Čech compactification and its remainder is also dense there. Maybe there are other examples, but this was first that came to my mind.

**Question 2)** Can this happen also for other than Stone-Čech compactifications, or not?

I am assuming Hausdorff compactifications.
Thank you for providing any insights.

Comment: For your first question, there exist compact spaces which aren't locally compact (Alexandroff compactifixation of $\mathbb{Q}$) so those provide a counter-example.

Comment: What happens when you try to prove 1?  Let $X$ be completely regular and not locally compact.  Let $a \in X$ be a point with no compact neighborhood in $X$.  Show $a$ is in the closure of $\beta X \setminus X$.  Then consider a point $a$ with a compact neighborhood in $X$.

Comment: What is your definition of "compactification"?  (In particular, it makes a big difference whether you require your spaces to be Hausdorff.)

Comment: @EricWofsey I am assuming Hausdorff compactifications. Added to the question.

Comment: The wording of your question is confusing. Your opening sentence contains the confusing phrase "its compactification", which seems to imply some particular compactification, although I doubt that is the intent. Is your intention to say that "Any space has to be dense in *any of its compactifications*" ?

Comment: @GEdgar I am sorry, I don´t understand your proof. How do I show the $a$ is in the closure of remainder? And then what? Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:** No.

Let $X = [0,1] \setminus N$ with $N  = \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$. This space is not locally compact because $0$ does not have any compact neigborhood. It has $[0,1]$ as a compactification, but here it has $N$ as a remainder which is not dense.

**Question 2:** Yes.

Daniel Wainfleet has given an example: Take $X = [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$. It has $[0,1]$ as a compactification different from Stone-Čech compactification, and the remainder is dense.

Comment: I have a related Q that I have not yet solved:  Let $X$ be completely regular,  and NO non-empty open subset of $X$ has compact closure. If $id_X:X\to Y$ is a compactification (where $Y$ is $T_2$) then is $Y\setminus X$ dense in $Y$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I thought about it, but I do no have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be a compact $T_2$ space. Suppose $$D\subsetneqq C=\overline C=\overline D\subsetneqq Y.$$ Let $X$ be the subspace $D\cup (Y\setminus C).$

Then id$_X:X\to Y$ is a compactification of the non-compact space $X.$ Its remainder is $C\setminus D,$ which is disjoint from the non-empty set $Y\setminus C.$

So $Y\setminus C$ is a non-empty open subset of $Y$ which is disjoint from the remainder.

Example: With the usual topology, let $Y=[0,2]$ and $C=[0,1]$ and $D=C\cap \Bbb Q.$

Comment: @KritikerderElche .The Q is whether the remainder, in Y, of the compactification of a non-locally-compact space X, $must$ be dense in Y, and the A is no.

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was not expedient.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet How can the $D$ be subspace of $C$ and in the same time its closure?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova . D is dense in C, but D$\ne$C, as stated and as in the example.

Comment: @KritikerderElche . OK. Understood.